Maximo 7.6.1.2, How can I change the JSON Response URL based on asset status
How can you change the JSON Response URL when syncing data between Maximo and GIS based on the status of the Asset?  For example, the URL that is defined in Map Manager for this type of feature class might be something like this: https:\arcgisservername\server\rest\service\featureservicename\FeatureServer\1\
I would like to change the layer number to '2' instead of '1' if the status of the asset is RETIRED or ABANDONED.
